# Converting Double To Int using type casting in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to convert `Double` to `Int` using Type Casting.

This is my code:

```
let number:Int = 3.0 as Int
```

It is showing an error:

> *Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to type 'Int' in coercion*

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not just `Int(3.0)`?

Comment: Actually i want to convert using Type Casting operator.

Comment: As you have tried, it does not work if you use `as`. Since you can't overload the `as` operator, you can't _make_ it work. You should use `Int(3.0)` instead.

Comment: In fact, you should use `let number = 3`

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. Unlike Objective-C Swift (strong typed) numeric types are not interchangeable by bridge cast. And what is the purpose to cast a type to another in a **declaration** line?

Comment: To @Gereon’s point, what’s the purpose of creating a Double to immediately convert it to an Int? Just make it an Int from the start. You can’t just use `as` because what would `3.5 as Int` return? 3? 4? You have to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only Int type to solve this issue
And I think the better way is not to cast from Double to Int, just create new value of Int type with Int(value: Double)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Int()` initializer.

`Int` and `Double` are completely unrelated types. Writing `someDouble as Int` is exactly as invalid as writing `someViewController as Character`.

In other C-like languages, the cast operator is dual purpose. It does both casts and conversions. Downcasting an object from a super type to a sub type does a type check, but performs no actual change of the value. But a conversion from `double` to `int` calls a function to do the conversion, that completely changes around the bits.

Swift's casting operator is more focused. It casts. For anything else, we use initializers.